# Rails scope multiple attributes in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model, scope

I’m trying to set up a scope on my `Job` model to show me records that match the following:

- `survey_date` is in the past.
- `survey_file` has a value.
- `quote_file` has no value.

How might I edit the following to make this scope work?

```
scope :awaiting_quote, lambda { where('survey_date < ? AND survey_file = ? AND quote_file = ?', Time.now, true, false) }
```

I’m not using class methods in this instance, because the scope is being used by ActiveAdmin, which requires it to be a model scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `IS NOT NULL` and `IS NULL` instead of `true` or `false`.

```
scope :awaiting_quote, lambda { where('survey_date < ? AND survey_file IS NOT NULL AND quote_file IS NULL', Time.now) }
```